# Argument 2 passed to Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin::afterPlace()

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, paypal-express

I am trying to make a payment with PayPal and place the order, at the link **paypal/express/placeOrder/** is showing me this issue:

*Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin::afterPlace() must implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface, null given, called in ...*

This is the code on line 119:

```
public function afterPlace(OrderManagementInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order): OrderInterface
{
    $itemsById = $itemsBySku = $itemsToSell = [];
    foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
        if (!isset($itemsById[$item->getProductId()])) {
            $itemsById[$item->getProductId()] = 0;
        }
        $itemsById[$item->getProductId()] += $item->getQtyOrdered();
    }
    $productSkus = $this->getSkusByProductIds->execute(array_keys($itemsById));
    $productTypes = $this->getProductTypesBySkus->execute($productSkus);

    foreach ($productSkus as $productId => $sku) {
        if (false === $this->isSourceItemManagementAllowedForProductType->execute($productTypes[$sku])) {
            continue;
        }

        $itemsBySku[$sku] = (float)$itemsById[$productId];
        $itemsToSell[] = $this->itemsToSellFactory->create([
            'sku' => $sku,
            'qty' => -(float)$itemsById[$productId]
        ]);
    }

    $websiteId = (int)$order->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $websiteCode = $this->websiteRepository->getById($websiteId)->getCode();
    $stockId = (int)$this->stockByWebsiteIdResolver->execute((int)$websiteId)->getStockId();

    $this->checkItemsQuantity->execute($itemsBySku, $stockId);

    /** @var SalesEventInterface $salesEvent */
    $salesEvent = $this->salesEventFactory->create([
        'type' => SalesEventInterface::EVENT_ORDER_PLACED,
        'objectType' => SalesEventInterface::OBJECT_TYPE_ORDER,
        'objectId' => (string)$order->getEntityId()
    ]);
    $salesChannel = $this->salesChannelFactory->create([
        'data' => [
            'type' => SalesChannelInterface::TYPE_WEBSITE,
            'code' => $websiteCode
        ]
    ]);

    $this->placeReservationsForSalesEvent->execute($itemsToSell, $salesChannel, $salesEvent);
    return $order;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Our current Magento Version is 2.3.9 and, previously we had 2.3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According above details the error is for 2nd argument OrderInterface $order. Please check you have give correct class which is expecting `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface.`

The above error says 2nd argument is acting as null.